# Updating Laravel from 5.4 to 7*

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i recently tried to update an old Laravelproject from 5.4 to 7*. Can I only do this step by step, so first go to 5.5 and then 5.6 and so on or is there any other solution?

Currently i´ve tried to update to 5.5 and went along the laravel documentation but this didn´t went well.

```
 composer update
    Loading composer repositories with package information
    Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
    Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

      Problem 1
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.47
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.46
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.45
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.44
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.43
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.42
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.41
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.40
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.39
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.38
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.37
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.36
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.35
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.34
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.33
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.32
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.31
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.30
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.29
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.28
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.27
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.26
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.25
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.24
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.23
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.22
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.21
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.20
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.19
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.18
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.17
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.16
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.15
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.14
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.13
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.12
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.11
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.10
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.9
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.8
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.7
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.6
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.5
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.4
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.3
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.2
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.1
        - barryvdh/laravel-snappy v0.3.3 requires illuminate/support 5.0.x|5.1.x|5.2.x|5.3.x|5.4.x -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.4.0], illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v5.0.22, v5.0.25, v5.0.26, v5.0.28, v5.0.33, v5.0.4, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8, v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, 
    v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9].
        - barryvdh/laravel-snappy v0.3.2 requires illuminate/filesystem 5.0.x|5.1.x|5.2.x|5.3.x|5.4.x -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.4.0], illuminate/filesystem[v5.0.0, v5.0.22, v5.0.25, v5.0.26, v5.0.28, v5.0.33, v5.0.4, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8, v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9].
        - barryvdh/laravel-snappy v0.3.3 requires illuminate/filesystem 5.0.x|5.1.x|5.2.x|5.3.x|5.4.x -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.4.0], illuminate/filesystem[v5.0.0, v5.0.22, v5.0.25, v5.0.26, v5.0.28, v5.0.33, v5.0.4, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8, v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9].
        - barryvdh/laravel-snappy v0.3.1 requires illuminate/support 5.0.x|5.1.x|5.2.x|5.3.x -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v5.0.22, v5.0.25, v5.0.26, v5.0.28, v5.0.33, v5.0.4, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8, v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4].
        - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v5.5.0, v5.4.0].
        - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.0.22|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.0.25|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.0.26|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.0.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.0.33|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.0.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.1.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.1.13|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.1.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.1.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.1.20|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.1.22|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.1.25|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.1.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.1.30|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.1.31|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.1.41|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.1.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.1.8|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.2.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.2.19|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.2.21|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.2.24|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.2.25|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.2.26|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.2.27|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.2.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.2.31|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.2.32|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.2.37|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.2.43|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.2.45|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.2.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.2.7|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.3.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.3.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.3.23|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.3.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.4.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.4.13|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.4.17|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.4.19|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.4.27|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.4.36|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.4.9|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.22|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.25|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.26|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.33|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.13|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.20|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.22|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.25|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.30|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.31|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.41|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.8|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.19|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.21|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.24|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.25|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.26|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.27|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.31|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.32|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.37|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.43|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.45|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.7|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.3.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.3.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.3.23|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.3.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.13|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.17|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.19|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.27|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.36|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.9|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
        - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.5.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.5.0, v5.5.1, v5.5.10, v5.5.11, v5.5.12, v5.5.13, v5.5.14, v5.5.15, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.18, v5.5.19, v5.5.2, v5.5.20, v5.5.21, v5.5.22, v5.5.23, v5.5.24, v5.5.25, v5.5.26, v5.5.27, v5.5.28, v5.5.29, v5.5.3, v5.5.30, v5.5.31, v5.5.32, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.38, v5.5.39, v5.5.4, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.42, v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.5.45, v5.5.46, v5.5.47, v5.5.48, v5.5.5, v5.5.6, v5.5.7, v5.5.8, v5.5.9].
        - Installation request for barryvdh/laravel-snappy ^0.3.1 -> satisfiable by barryvdh/laravel-snappy[v0.3.1, v0.3.2, v0.3.3].
```

Here is my composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.4",
        "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
        "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.2",
        "laravelcollective/html": "^5.4",
        "doctrine/dbal": "~2.3",
        "caouecs/laravel-lang": "~3.0",
        "overtrue/laravel-lang": "^3.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.0",
        "components/font-awesome": "^4.7",
        "dimsemenov/magnific-popup": "^1.1",
        "barryvdh/laravel-snappy": "^0.3.1",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "laravel/scout": "^3.0",
        "tamayo/laravel-scout-elastic": "^3.0",
        "elasticsearch/elasticsearch": "^5.1",
        "iatstuti/laravel-nullable-fields": "^1.4"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "3.1.*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "3.1.*",
        "ignasbernotas/laravel-model-generator": "^1.1"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I am no expert, but it appears to be saying that some of the addons you have used are not supported in the version you are attempting to upgrade to

Comment: Try a more recent version of `"barryvdh/laravel-snappy": "^0.3.1",` There is a version 0.47.

Comment: Seems like it worked for me to use ""barryvdh/laravel-snappy": "^0.4.7",". THANK YOU! But is there no other solution than going step by step to 7.* ?

Comment: You *can* make such a large upgrade but the key point here is that your add-ons and "other composer packages" must be compatible with it.  The differences between "Laravel 5" and "Laravel 7" are not small ones.